# Getting StatusCode: 400, Bad Request when sending Apple Receipt on server

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

Hi I applied AppPurchase on my app that is using xamarin forms and my app is sending fine the Google Receipt on my Server(azure).

But getting StatusCode: 400, BadRequest error when sending the Apple Receipt.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<PurchaseResult> PurchaseAsync(AppleReceipt receipt)
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    devicePlatform = "ios";
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    devicePlatform = "android";
                    break;
            }

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("deviceplatform", devicePlatform);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("serviceid", serviceId);

            InitializeApiClientUser(true);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{Constants.ApiUrl}purchaseapple{codePrefix}{Constants.ApiKey}");

            var s = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };



            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress, receipt);

            CocoSharpControlUI.DisplayAlert("RESPONSE", response.ToString());
            client = new HttpClient();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PurchaseResult>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
```

Comment: Apple's `/verifyReceipt` endpoint has been down today, that could be part of it: https://twitter.com/RevenueCat/status/1220741181841166336?s=20

Comment: Verification is fine on my end however the issue is sending the receipt to my server.